# How we can use keyboard Shortcut key like CTRL+F3 in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

How to set and use shortcut key in SQL SERVER for execute query ?

```
select * from tableName
```

and only type *tableName* and press key and execute query

Comment: SQL Server, itself, has no UI and no knowledge of keyboards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just go to  Tool -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Query Shortcuts
and then customize it...

Answer (score 2):

In SSMS go to

> Tool -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard -> Query Shortcuts

and you can set it up. Remember to leave a space after your command and close exisiting query window. Once shortcuts are set up, you can select your object and press the shortcut combination. It will pick up the query and add your selected object to the end of query and execute complete query.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio supports custom shortcuts: Tools -> Options -> Keyboard:
Among them, Alt + F1, Ctrl + 1, Ctrl + 2 is the system pre-defined shortcut keys.